JSON decode error on POST of empty data expecting to get the API response message
On POST of login data, I expect to get the API response message. I get API message if I POST with data, but if I leave the textfield empty and click the button, I get error :

…dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character '<' around line 1, column 1." UserInfo={NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0, NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character '<' around line 1, column 1.})))
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

The localization is not working.
func userAuthRequest<T>(url: String, parameters: [String : Any], type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> where T : Decodable {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        return Fail(error: URLError(.badURL)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("en", forHTTPHeaderField: "lang")
    let postData = parameters.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }
        .joined(separator: "&")
        .data(using: .utf8)
    request.httpBody = postData
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
        .mapError { _ in APIError.serverError }
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func signUp() {
    let parameters = [
        "name": name,
        "password": password,
        "mobile": phone,
    ]
    isLoading = true
    service.userAuthRequest(url: Config.baseURL+"signup", parameters: parameters, type: SignUpResponse.self)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] completion in
            self?.isLoading = false
            switch completion{
            case .finished:
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
                self?.showAlert = true
                print("err\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
            if response.status {
                self?.isAuthenticated = true
                if let code = response.data?.code{
                    self?.verificationCode = code
                }
                if let phone = response.data?.mobile{
                    self?.phone = phone
                }
            } else {
                print("res: \(response.message)")
                self?.errorMessage = response.message
                self?.showAlert = true
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

struct SignUpResponse: Codable{
    let status: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: SignUpData?
}

struct SignUpData: Codable{
    let mobile: String?
    let code: Int?
}

and the localization is now working too. It works well on Postman and response with Arabic when lang = "ar".
request.setValue("ar", forHTTPHeaderField: "lang")


When you use postman do you get a JSON response, and error or an http message?
If you get a JSON response, does it match the SignUpResponse?
In the Swift code, try to add print("--> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))").
For the language, you could try using
request.setValue("en", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language"), or "Content-Language"

@workingdogsupportUkraine
--> data: Optional("password=&device_type=iOS&mobile=")
when post empty data I get this response on postman:
{
"status": false,
"message": "The password field is required.",
"data": null
}
but in swift code I get message above..
and in language I tried "lang", "Accept-Language", and "Content-Language", but not working

--> data: Optional("password=&mobile=&name=")**

as I understand, postman can generate the Swift code for you. You could try that and see if you are missing something.

Where did you put the print("--> data:...) statement, is it in the .map(\.data)?

@workingdogsupportUkraine opps, when print it in
.map { data, response -> Data in
print("--> data: (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")
return data
}
I get html response in console

just return html when post empty data .. why , what is wrong in code

If an empty parameters is the real problem, you could try this in userAuthRequest:
let postData = ....data(using: .utf8)! and
if !postData.isEmpty {      request.httpBody = postData  } else {      // ... stop execution of the URLSession     return ....  }
